# Get specific element with highest value in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, get, highest

I'm new to java and I'm having a problem with `ArrayList`. I want to get the highest value from Jozef and Klaus.

`ArrayList` looks like:

```
|  Name        | Age|
+--------------+----+
| Jozef Coin   | 55 |    
| Jozef Coin   | 56 |    
| Jozef Coin   | 57 |
| Klaus Neumer | 34 |
| Klaus Neumer | 31 |
| Klaus Neumer | 59 |
```

This is my code so far, it only returns the highest value in the `arraylist`.

```
Person b = persons.get(0)

for(Person p: persons){    
      if(p.getAge() >= b.getAge()){    
         b = p;    
           System.out.println(b.toString());    
      }    
}
```

I'm probably way over my head but I'd love to know if this is possible and if so there is an solution to this.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What does the `Person` class look like?

Comment: So instead of highest in the list you want highest for each person?

Comment: Yes exactly Sam Orozco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for your task

```
public class CompareAge implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getAge().compareTo(p2.getAge());
    }
}
```

Then use that `CompareAge` class like as follows

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList, new CompareAge());
myArrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1); //Retrieve the last object
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a great solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer unless we know the methods in the Person class, however this would be the general way I would do it.

```
Person b = persons.get(0)
int jozefHighest = 0;
int klausHighest = 0;

for(Person p: persons){

      if(p.getName().startsWith("Jozef") {
        if(p.getAge() > jozefHighest)
            jozefHighest = p.getAge)_
      } else if (p.getName().startsWith("Klaus")) {
        if(p.getAge() > klausHighest)
            klausHighest = p.getAge()
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8 is Cool!

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
    OptionalInt maxValue = IntStream.of(a).max();
    System.out.println("Max Value: " + maxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single step in Java 8:

```
Map<String, Integer> oldestMap = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName,
        Collectors.maxBy(Person::getAge).get());
```

You now have a map from name to maximum age.